# how do i keep my all menus in a dropdown item and home menue at the left point?

Tags: android, xml, android-actionbar, android-menu

i have added menues in my menue item in xml.now i want to keep the home icon only at the very right of the action bar and the others will remain in three dots and when someone clicks them they will collapse down in a group.
that is my xml

```
<item
    android:id="@+id/action_settings"
    android:orderInCategory="100"
    android:showAsAction="never"
    android:title="@string/action_settings"/>
<item android:id="@+id/Homebar"
    android:title="Home"
    android:orderInCategory="1"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/infobar"
    android:title="Info"
    android:orderInCategory="2"
    android:showAsAction="collapseActionView"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/servicebar"
    android:title="Services"
    android:orderInCategory="3"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/onlinetoolsbar"
    android:title="Online tools"
    android:orderInCategory="4"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
<item android:id="@+id/mediacenterbar"
    android:title="Media center"
    android:orderInCategory="5"
    android:showAsAction="always"
    />
```

Comment: Do you want the "Home" item to the right of the overflow? Or only to the right of the other action buttons (and left of the overflow)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i solved it by adding an icon at the very right of the top and put the drop down on action.